# BeautifulSoup How to find only tags containing the tag?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

There is a part of the html code of the page I parse:

```
<td>
  <a class="soup" href="link">1</a>
</td>
<td>
  <a class="soup" href="link">2</a>
  <br>
    <img src="/any.gif">
  </br>
</td>
<td>
  <a class="soup" href="link">3</a>
</td>
<td>
  <a class="soup" href="link">4</a>
  <br>
    <img src="/any.gif">
  </br>
</td>
<td>
  <a class="soup" href="link">5</a>
</td>
```

Question: How to get all only those td that contain br and img?

UPD:  i try to use `soup.find('img', {'src': '/any.gif'}).findPreviousSibling('a')` But he finds only one `<a>` 
**(The main goal is to get all only `<a>` next to them `<br><img></br>` )**

Comment: What have you tried so far to get the desired output?

Comment: @GaneshTata i try to use soup.find('img', {'src': '/any.gif'}).findPreviousSibling('a') But he finds only one <a> (The main goal is to get all only <a> next to them <br><img></br> )

Comment: Please post this in the question itself, so that people can help you find a solution

Comment: If you start out with invalid HTML, what comes out of a parser is anybody's guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just small improvement to your code

```
for img in soup.find_all('img', {'src': '/any.gif'}):
   if img.findPreviousSibling('a') is not None:
     a=img.findPreviousSibling('a')
     print a['href']
```